# WooCommerce - empty cart when proceed to checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I recently updated `WooCommerce` to newest version `(2.2.6)` and I have an issue.

When I'm logged in - everything works fine.

When customer isn't logged - after proceeding to the checkout he gets cart page with empty cart.

I `var_dump`'ed `$_SESSION` and `WooCommerce`'s cart before checkout and everything what should be there - it was:

```
global $woocommerce;

var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($woocommerce->cart->get_cart());
```

Note: On localhost everything works FINE, when I'm logged or not. On domain - like above.

Any ideas? :/

Comment: Is the session module enabled on the server, assuming Apache?

Comment: Yes, it is. This site is using translation plugin, which also requires session and here is all OK - before and after update. WP_DEBUG gives no errors, probably because automatic redirect from /order to /cart

Comment: Do cross check if your host is wp engine ??? http://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/

Comment: Possible template issue? Some of the hooks have changed between versions. Do you have a custom template in place for the checkout page? If so, if you use the default, what happens?

Comment: @Fresher - What do you mean?

rnevius - I use default wooocommerce pages template for now :/

Comment: And I updated only WooCommerce, rest without changes